# Why/How do higher amp hour batteries for tools provide more power?

Tags: batteries

I have seen power tool brands have battery packs ranging from 1.5Ah to 9Ah. Their advertising indicates that the larger amp hour battery packs can run the tool longer and with more power (such as a circular saw cutting through thicker material). These are all 18v battery packs, so I can only assume that there is circuitry within the packs that are limiting the amount of current per cell. That way, the packs with more cells can provide more current. Is that correct?

If it is a circuit to limit current (for short/heat protection purposes?), how are they going about doing this? Just an off the shelf solution they stick in there?

Comment: Higher Ah packs have more batteries in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batteries for power tools are made of a set of more-or-less standard primary "Li-Ion cells", typically of 18650 size. The cells came in different capacities, but overall the capacity is limited by current state of technology given the fixed cell volume. There are high-capacity cells, with higher energy density, and cells with less nameplate capacity.

One important thing for power tools is an ability to supply high peak currents to overcome start-up inrush currents for motors, and to handle load. So the battery cells must be of "high-discharge" type. High discharge means smaller internal resistance (ESR) and therefore require thicker foil electrodes and current collectors. As such, the overall power density (given the same volume of the cell) is smaller. That's why mass-produced power tools use cells of seemingly lower capacity, say 1500 mAh.

Now, to increase total battery capacity they use a bunch of same cells (or series string of cells) in PARALLEL. This increases not only the overall capacity (6 cells of 1500 mAh give about 9000 mAh battery), but automatically it decreases the overall ESR (six ESRs in parallel result in 1/6 of the original ESR). Thus the battery becomes more "powerful" automatically (can deliver more current). So there is no artificial "current limiter" inside power tool battery pack (besides the fire protection), the limitation comes from property of individual primary cells used to make the battery.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I didn't know there was an internal resistance at play in the batteries that is causing a limit of the current. I thought lithium cells would pretty much dump as much current as possible given the chance and burn themselves up doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, higher amp-hours battery packs have lower internal resistance which reduces the voltage droop at higher current draws which equates to more power output for the same motor and voltage.

The other thing is that for the same amount of usage, a larger pack will have drained proportionally less than a smaller pack which means it's voltage will not have decreased as much. This equates to being able to run at higher power for longer periods of time, but no more power than at the peak power of the smaller pack (the above paragraph notwithstanding).

But if you asked me for what the answer really is, I would say the half-truths of marketing.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is a circuit to limit current (for short/heat protection
>   purposes?), how are they going about doing this? Just an off the shelf
>   solution they stick in there?

It depends on the manufacture and model of battery. Some have a full BMS built into the battery and possibly also a DC to DC converter (like the dewalt 18V system, the BMS is in the thing between the contacts and the battery). I doubt other manufacturers are limiting the capacity with a charge controller circuit, the batteries most likely have smaller capacity cells. You can easily tell by pulling one of the battery packs open and checking the datasheets from the battery manufacturer which list the capacity (and sometimes it's listed on the cells).

Typical batteries have 5ish cells and sometimes have a BMS, and use more cells for more capacity. Some battery packs only have cells and the BMS is in the charge controller and/or power tool (the newer 20V dewalts.)

> That way, the packs with more cells can provide more current. Is that
>   correct?

The more cells you have, the more voltage you have if the cells are in series. Sometimes two packs of cells are paralleled for additional capacity.

Comment: I think the OP is specifically asking why packs with larger mAh, in the same voltage are advertised to provide more power given that they are being used on the same tool with the same motor.

Comment: @Toor Yes, that is what I meant. I knew that the cells would be paralleled to provide more Ah with the same voltage. It just isn't intuitive why they tool would be more powerful since the voltage remains the same.